# Phaser issue, all my tiles have null properties when selected

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've been working on a project found here -> https://paperambi.glitch.me/

as seen in console, all my tiles are recorded null, and therefore i cant get their index property, what is wrong with my tiles, and is there anyway to fix it?

Heres an example, when you click on tiles to get properties, its null
and if you add index, it responds with cannot find null of index.

Am I using the wrong function, or have something wrong with my tiles?

code sandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/31xpvv85om?hidenavigation=1&module=/js/index.js&moduleview=1&file=/js/index.js:0-3327
all code for the example

```js
/**
 * Author: Michael Hadley, mikewesthad.com
 * Asset Credits:
 *  - Tileset by 0x72 under CC-0, https://0x72.itch.io/16x16-industrial-tileset
 */

import Phaser from "phaser";

const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  parent: "game-container",
  backgroundColor: "#1d212d",
  pixelArt: true,
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
  }
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
let controls;
let marker;
let shiftKey;
let groundLayer;

function preload() {
  this.load.image(
    "tiles",
    "../assets/tilesets/0x72-industrial-tileset-32px-extruded.png"
  );
  this.load.tilemapTiledJSON(
    "map",
    "../assets/tilemaps/platformer-simple.json"
  );
}

function create() {
  const map = this.make.tilemap({ key: "map" });
  const tiles = map.addTilesetImage(
    "0x72-industrial-tileset-32px-extruded",
    "tiles"
  );

  // Same setup as static layers
  map.createLayer("Background", tiles);
  groundLayer = map.createLayer("Ground", tiles);
  map.createLayer("Foreground", tiles);

  shiftKey = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SHIFT);

  // Set up the arrows to control the camera
  const cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  const controlConfig = {
    camera: this.cameras.main,
    left: cursors.left,
    right: cursors.right,
    up: cursors.up,
    down: cursors.down,
    speed: 0.5
  };
  controls = new Phaser.Cameras.Controls.FixedKeyControl(controlConfig);

  // Limit the camera to the map size
  this.cameras.main.setBounds(0, 0, map.widthInPixels, map.heightInPixels);

  // Create a simple graphic that can be used to show which tile the mouse is over
  marker = this.add.graphics();
  marker.lineStyle(5, 0xffffff, 1);
  marker.strokeRect(0, 0, map.tileWidth, map.tileHeight);
  marker.lineStyle(3, 0xff4f78, 1);
  marker.strokeRect(0, 0, map.tileWidth, map.tileHeight);

  // Help text that has a "fixed" position on the screen
  this.add
    .text(
      16,
      16,
      "Arrow keys to scroll\nLeft-click to draw tiles\nShift + left-click to erase",
      {
        font: "18px monospace",
        fill: "#000000",
        padding: { x: 20, y: 10 },
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
      }
    )
    .setScrollFactor(0);
}

function update(time, delta) {
  controls.update(delta);

  // Convert the mouse position to world position within the camera
  const worldPoint = this.input.activePointer.positionToCamera(
    this.cameras.main
  );

  // Place the marker in world space, but snap it to the tile grid. If we convert world -> tile and
  // then tile -> world, we end up with the position of the tile under the pointer
  const pointerTileXY = groundLayer.worldToTileXY(worldPoint.x, worldPoint.y);
  const snappedWorldPoint = groundLayer.tileToWorldXY(
    pointerTileXY.x,
    pointerTileXY.y
  );
  marker.setPosition(snappedWorldPoint.x, snappedWorldPoint.y);

  // Draw or erase tiles (only within the groundLayer)
  if (this.input.manager.activePointer.isDown) {
    if (shiftKey.isDown) {
      groundLayer.removeTileAtWorldXY(worldPoint.x, worldPoint.y);
    } else {
      groundLayer.putTileAtWorldXY(353, worldPoint.x, worldPoint.y);
      var tile = groundLayer.getTileAt(
        worldPoint.x,
        worldPoint.y
      ); //.index;
      console.log(tile);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the function you are using `getTileAt` *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.TilemapLayer.html#getTileAt__anchor))*, with world coordinates, there are two easy solutions:

1. you could use your variable `pointerTileXY` like:

   ```
   var tile = groundLayer.getTileAt(
      pointerTileXY.x,
      pointerTileXY.y
   );
   ```
2. Or you could use the function `getTileAtWorldXY` *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.TilemapLayer.html#getTileAtWorldXY__anchor))*

   ```
   var tile = groundLayer.getTileAtWorldXY(
      worldPoint.x,
      worldPoint.y
   );
   ```